# Prove that a certain element is not trivial in $B_3$

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

Let $B_3$ be the group defined by $$B_3=\langle \sigma_1,\sigma_2\mid\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1=\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\rangle\text{.}$$

I need to prove that the element $$g=\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2^{-2}\sigma_1^{-2}\sigma_2^2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^{-2}\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\sigma_1^{-1}$$
is not trivial in $B_3$.

I have tried to prove the image of $g$ is not trivial in the natrual quotient homomorphism $B_3\to B_3/\langle\sigma_1^3=1\rangle$; but am not sure how to complete the argument, or should I use this approach at all. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The following image is for those who need a geometric meaning of this question; but I don't know if it is relevant.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to write down the quotient map $B_3 \to PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and have you checked whether the image of your element in there is nontrivial?

Comment: I am not familiar with that; how is the map defined?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_between_B3_and_the_modular_group

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan! Will try it.

Comment: If that fails, then there are efficient methods for solving the word problem in braid groups. See for example the discussion http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91425/the-word-problem-in-braid-groups

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt! I think the quotient map that Qiaochu mentioned works; but thank you anyway!!